# Is this statement considered to be a fact?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, phrase-meaning

Player A has lost to player B most of times in a game that is not all about luck (consider a mobile soccer game).

Player A claims that he didn't use his full power. (It's just a claim, and we can't judge he is right or not)

Is the statement "Probability of player B being better than A is more than 50%" considered as a fact by definition?

Comment: This is a question about statistics, not a language & usage question. Maybe try over at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about statistics, not English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaguely, yes.
Specifically, no.

Let me explain:

If we flip a coin (heads I win, tails you win), and I win 75% of the games, **that does not automatically make me a better player**. I just got lucky, there was no skill involved.

Your previous win ratio, the probability of you winning a future game, and the odds of you being a better player **can** be connected, but that isn't automatically always the case.

For coin-flipping, there is a clear disconnect between player skill and player win chance.
If we e.g. consider Formula 1 racing, there is a strong correlation between having won many races, having a shot at winning more races, and being a good Formula 1 pilot.

Even if we only consider games in which skill is the **sole** deciding factor, that still doesn't account for flukes and fakeouts.

---

I'll give you a real world example:

My friend taught me to play billiards. A few years later, we are playing competitively.

At the end of the season, I had won 34 out of 36 games played (against other opponents). My friend ended up winning 22 out of 36 games. We played in the same league, and opponents were drawn randomly, on average we played against opponents of equal skill.
Looking at those statistics; would you **definitively** conclude that I am the better player?

However, I could hardly win any game I played against him. For some inexplicable reason, I won <25% of games against him.
Looking at those statistics; would you **definitively** conclude that he is  the better player?

The past win ratio cannot be used to conclude anything about the skill of the player, because skill can be a very different thing. For example:

- There are sports in which personal performance is the only part of the game. Players are not allowed to make eachother lose. (e.g. track athletics)
- There are games, based on skill, where it is part of the game to not only make your team score points, but prevent the other team from scoring points (football, chess, billiards)
- There are games that include random chance (even if only partially), where the outcome is often not skill-based but rather luck-based. However, for the example of poker, there is still a level of skill that can influence the results, e.g. by bluffing. However, a new player who is oblivious to bluffing and through some stroke of luck consistently keeps getting better cards will still win the game regardless of the opponent's skill.

If I won 90% of athletics sport against my friend, it would be correct to say I am the better athlete. Beacuse my result was not influenced by my competitors.

If I won 90% of chess games, I can't conclusively say that I am objectively better than my opponent. I can only say that in *these* games I played against my opponent, I beat him.
He could come up with a strategy that completely crushes me in the future, I cannot make any predictions about that.

So to conclude: No, you cannot **definitively** state that **as a fact**. You can call it a guess, or a prediction, but not a fact. The only fact you can state is the win ratio of past games, since the outcome of these games is no longer disputable.